# Is there a way to get the table you are parsing by using pairs/ipairs within the loop?

Tags: lua

Well, just as summary... I have a pairs loop like this:

```lua
for k, v in pairs(LS_Module) do
    local newName = "LS_" .. k
    LS_Module[newName] = v
    rawset(M_Class, k, v)
end
```

And I wondered if couldn't be made it more "generic" by not having to refer to the table being parsed explicitly inside the loop, but somehow get it from *pairs* or wherever... Of course, I could make it a function or assign the table to a variable before and then just use that variable in both places instead the table itself and that's what I was about to do since there doesn't seem to be a way to do what I want, but you never really know until you ask here, so...

Comment: Sounds like you want a custom iterator https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html

Comment: @Luke100000 Hmm, never thought I could need to write my own iterators that way and, despite I don't think in this case will worth's it going so far, thanks for commenting and pointing me out to that possibility should it might come in handy at some point... Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by creating a replacement for `next` that returns `t` too, and then a replacement for `pairs` that uses that, like this:

```
local function nextt(t, k)
    local k2, v = next(t, k)
    return k2, v, t
end

local function pairst(t)
    return nextt, t, nil
end

for k, v, t in pairst(LS_Module) do
    -- the table is "t" now
end
```

By the way, [the Lua reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-next) says "You should not assign any value to a non-existent field in a table during its traversal", but you appear to be doing that, so you'll probably get unwanted results from your loop.

Comment: Yes, in a quick test it works, thank you! I kind of expected a less "convoluted" solution/trick could be possible to make it really worthwhile after all (in this case at least), but I guess it is what it is and it's good to know anyway... Well, thank you again, and also for the "not assigning during traversal" advice, which will be taken into account :)